# Expected number of rolls of die until gcd/lcm exceeds certain value?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I was presented with the following problem:

> What is the expected number of rolls of a $n$-sided die until
>   i) the lcm of the rolls exceeds $k$?
>   ii) the gcd of the rolls exceeds $k$?

Is this something that can be analytically done, or must this be done numerically?

As a hint, I am told that for $n=10$ and $k=2018$, the EV for part i) converges to $18.8$, but that seems oddly low.

Could someone prod me the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: The answer in your example is not particularly low.  If you wanted the expected number of rolls to see all ten faces then this would be about $29.3$.  But here you only need to see faces $7$, $8$, $9$ and either of $5$ or $10$ to get a lowest common multiple above $2018$ (or indeed of $1261$ or more, since $2560$ is the only possibility)

Comment: @Henry I can see that now; how do you prove it analytically though?